# FilterPanel. InteractiveSearchPattern - list of possible values

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

Where can I find the list of all possible options/values I can assign to this property ?
So far I only found people using: "status:m"

filterPanel.InteractiveSearchPattern = "status:m"

Comment: out of curiosity, is there something specific you're hoping to find?

Comment: not really, it is more about the curiosity of what options are there apart from the one mentioned in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

great question!

uhhhhhh I don't think there's a list though :)

I did some digging through our support DB and found the following info. I have not had a chance to test these to validate.

- `InteractiveSearchPattern` can be set to the name of a filter to find, well, that specific filter (or a partial filter name to match multiple filters)
- `status:m` is abbreviated from `status:modified`, and will return a list of all modified filters
- `datatable:MyTable` should match all filters from a given data table
- `*` should match all columns (unclear if this is regex matching or not)

I inquired about this to TIBCO support, so if there are any additional points to list I'll make sure to update the answer :)